# bug in ISNUMERIC function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a problem with `ISNUMERIC` Function in SQL-server.

I have a table, which contains one column with `nvarchar` type. In this column I have such a values `123`, `241`, ... and sometimes string values like `LK`
My Query:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE ISNUMERIC([Column1]) = 1
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE CAST(cte.Column1 AS INT) > 8000
```

but this query returns this error message:

```
error converting data type nvarchar 'LK' to int
```

my expectation is, that the Common table expression filter all rows, which Column1 are numeric and not string? Is it correct?

Why do I receive this error?

Comment: It has to do with in which sequence SQL Server parses and executes the SQL. If you want to be sure, you'll have to use a temporary table instead of the CTE. Or depending on your server version, the try parse functions if you have access to them. 
However note that ISNUMERIC can return 1 for things you cannot parse to INT so your code fail elsewhere as well

Comment: Is there any alternative function in SQL server, which solve my problem?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4213.0 (X64) 
 Jun  9 2015 12:06:16 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Check out the TRY_CONVERT https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually no bug.

The CTE is a temporary view (or acts like a temporary view). So think on our query like querying a view. Most likely SQL will try first to go through all rows and get results from both scalars (isnumeric and the cast) then proceed to the filtering.

That being said, it will fail way before it will try to filter the data on the cast.

If you want to make it work just filter the data before in a temporary table or in a table variable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have the same problem with subselect It is also because of what you explained?

Comment: @Kaja Yes, subselects have the same issue. Subselects *don't* create a temporary table in any modern DB engine.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.tbl', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.tbl
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.tbl (val NVARCHAR(1000))
INSERT INTO dbo.tbl
VALUES ('123'), ('234'), ('LK'), ('8001')

ALTER TABLE dbo.tbl
    ADD val2 AS CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(val) = 1 THEN CAST(val AS INT) END
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.tbl
WHERE val2 > 8000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can force to materialize CTE table by adding `TOP X`, to avoid SQL server optimize the where condition to make it "short-circuit" like behavior.

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT TOP 10000000000000 
        *
    FROM (VALUES('1'), ('LK')) t(Column1)
    WHERE ISNUMERIC([Column1]) = 1
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE CAST(cte.Column1 AS INT) > 8000
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with how the query is parsed and executed. If adding a column as suggested by Devart is not possible, then using a temp table could be an alternate.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
Column1 nvarchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO MyTable
    VALUES ('123'),
    ('241'),
    ('LK'),
    ('786'),
    ('54321'),
    ('7999'),
    ('8001')

SELECT
    * INTO #TEMP
FROM MyTable
WHERE ISNUMERIC([Column1]) = 1

SELECT
    *
FROM #TEMP
WHERE CAST(Column1 AS int) > 8000

DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that SQL is a declarative language that imposes very little order on the operations. This is necessary to allow the engine to optimize the query.

One case where short-circuiting works is in a `case` statement. So you can try something like this:

```
drop table #tbl;

create table #tbl (txt varchar(10))
insert into  #tbl
 values ('123'), ('234'), ('LK'), ('9001')

select * from #tbl 
where 
 (
  case 
   when isnumeric(txt) = 1 then 
    case when cast(txt as int) > 8000 then 1 end 
  end
 ) = 1
```

I can't tell you how the performance is going to work out, though. In general, you should really use normalized data when possible - it allows SQL databases to really shine :)