# Query fails on "converting character string to smalldatetime data type"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, predicate, culture, date-conversion

I've been tasked with fixing some SQL code that doesn't work.  The query reads from a view against a predicate.  The query right now looks like so.

```
SELECT  TOP (100) Beginn
FROM  V_LLAMA_Seminare
//Removal of the following line makes the query successful, keeping it breaks it
where Beginn  > (select cast (getdate() as smalldatetime))
order by Beginn desc
```

When I run the above query, I am greeted with the following error.

```
Msg 295, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type.
```

I decided to remove the WHERE clause, and now it runs returning 100 rows.

At first, I thought that behind the scenes, SQL Server was somehow including my predicate when bringing back the View .  But then I investigated how the View was being created, especially the Beginn field, and at no point does it return a String.

Long story short, the column that becomes the Beginn field is a BIGINT timestamp like 201604201369....  The original user transforms this BIGINT to a smalldatetime using the following magic.

```
....
CASE WHEN ma.datum_dt = 0 
   THEN null 
   ELSE CONVERT(smalldatetime, SUBSTRING(CAST(ma.datum_dt AS varchar(max)),0,5) + '-' + 
   SUBSTRING(CAST(ma.datum_dt AS varchar(max)),5,2)  + '-' + 
   SUBSTRING(CAST(ma.datum_dt AS varchar(max)),7,2) +  ' ' + 
   SUBSTRING(CAST(ma.datum_dt AS varchar(max)),9,2) +':'+
   SUBSTRING(CAST(ma.datum_dt AS varchar(max)),11,2) +':' + 
   RIGHT(CAST(ma.datum_dt AS varchar(max)),2)) END AS Beginn
...
```

My last attempt at finding the problem was to query the view and run the function ISDATE over the Beginn column and see if it returned a 0 which it never did.

So my question is two fold, "Why does a predicate break something" and two "Where on earth is this string error coming from when the Beginn value is being formed from a BIGINT".

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36542569/5089204

Answer (score 1):

This problem is culture related...

Try this and then change the first `SET LANGUAGE` to `GERMAN`

```
SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH;
DECLARE @bi BIGINT=20160428001600;
SELECT CASE WHEN @bi = 0 
   THEN null 
   ELSE CONVERT(datetime, SUBSTRING(CAST(@bi AS varchar(max)),0,5) + '-' + 
   SUBSTRING(CAST(@bi AS varchar(max)),5,2)  + '-' + 
   SUBSTRING(CAST(@bi AS varchar(max)),7,2) +  ' ' + 
   SUBSTRING(CAST(@bi AS varchar(max)),9,2) +':'+
   SUBSTRING(CAST(@bi AS varchar(max)),11,2) +':' + 
   RIGHT(CAST(@bi AS varchar(max)),2)) END AS Beginn
```

It is a very bad habit to think, that date values look the same everywhere (*Oh no, my small application will never go international* ...)

Try to stick to culture independent formats like [ODBC or ISO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34275965/5089204)

#### EDIT

A very easy solution for you actually was to replace the blank with a "T"

```
   SUBSTRING(CAST(ma.datum_dt AS varchar(max)),7,2) +  'T' +
```

Then it's ISO 8601 and will convert...

Comment: It didn't work.  I'm thinking that the server is doing some kind of implicit conversion but I don't have enough privileges for SHOWPLAN ='( (and I'll probably never get them).

Answer (score 0):

The solution was found after looking through @Shnugo's comment.  When I took my query which contained the Bigint->Datetime conversion logic, and put it into a CTE with "TOP 100000000" to avoid any implicit conversion actions, my query worked.  Here is what my view looks like now with some unimportant parts omitted.

```
---Important part---
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[V_SomeView] AS
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT TOP 1000000000 ma.id AS MA_ID,
---Important part---
   vko.extkey AS ID_VKO,
   vko.text AS Verkaufsorganisation,
   fi.f7000 AS MDM_Nr,
   vf.f7105 AS SAPKdnr,
   CASE WHEN ma.datum_dt = 0 --Conversion logic
   CASE WHEN ma.endedatum_dt = 0 --Conversion logic
   CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),art.text) AS Art,
    .....
FROM [ucrm].[dbo].[CRM_MA] ma,
[ucrm].[dbo].[CRM_fi] fi,
[ucrm].[dbo].[CRM_vf] vf,
[ucrm].[dbo].[CRM_ka] vko,
[ucrm].[dbo].[CRM_ka] art,
[ucrm].[dbo].[CRM_ka] kat
where ma.loskz = 0
and fi.loskz = 0
and vf.loskz = 0
and fi.F7029 = 0
and vf.F7023 = 0
...
GROUP BY ma.id,
   vko.extkey,
   vko.text,
   fi.f7000 ,
   vf.f7105,
   ma.datum_dt,
   ma.endedatum_dt,
   ....
)
select * FROM CTE;
```